# Which Schema Field contain the html not Xhtml?

Tags: core-service, schema, componentpresentation

I am creating a schema and component using core service I create a XhtmlFieldDefinitionData field to putting the html but it take the Xhtml when I putting the html into this field it giving me serialize error so first I convert html into Xhtml but it remove many tag from the html and I want proper html on the filed.

what can I do for this and which type of field I create for the html so it directly take the html without convert into Xhtml.

Comment: Use plain text field if you really want exact HTML (which version?) in Tridion. But if this is a migration where authors will manage the content in the future, consider storing it in the proper XML and templating it to an appropriate format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alvin says, if you want to keep your exact HTML then upload the HTML as a string to a plain text field.

Uploading the HTML to a rich text field will cause the HTML to be "cleaned" to XHTML by the  Tridion XSLTs.

Again, to emphasize Alvin, consider properly abstracting content from presentation to get the full value of your Tridion system.